# Script simples de email php correto mas não envia, é o servidor?

Tags: php, html, script

Bom dia amigos, tenho o seguinte script porém não está enviando o e-mail, é o servidor?

http://paulinhomotos1.hospedagemdesites.ws/exemplo/form/form.html

HTML:

```
    <html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function checa_formulario(email){
if (email.nome.value == ""){
alert("Por Favor não deixe o seu nome em branco!!!");
email.nome.focus();
return (false);
}
if (email.email_from.value == ""){
alert("Por Favor não deixe o seu email em branco!!!");
email.email_from.focus();
return (false);
}
if (email.email.value == ""){
alert("não deixe o email destinatario em branco!!!");
email.email.focus();
return (false);
}
if (email.assunto.value == ""){
alert("não deixe o assunto em branco!!!");
email.assunto.focus();
return (false); 
}   
}
</script>
<title>Enviando texto</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<style type="text/css">
</style>
</head>
<body onLoad="document.email.nome.focus();">
<form onSubmit="return checa_formulario(this)" action="mail.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="email">
<table width="32%" border="0" align="center">
<tr>
<td><div align="right"><span class="texto">Name</span></div></td>
<td><input name="nome" type="text" id="nome"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="33%"><div align="right" class="texto">E-Mail</div></td>
<td width="67%"><input name="email_from" type="text" class="email"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><div align="right" class="texto"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><div align="right" class="texto">Subject</div></td>
<td><input name="assunto" type="text" id="assunto"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><div align="right" class="texto">Message</div></td>
<td><textarea name="mensagem" cols="50" rows="10" id="mensagem"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><div align="right" class="texto">Attachment</div></td>
<td><input name="arquivo" type="file"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> </td>
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Enviar"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
//pego os dados enviados pelo formulario
$nome = $_POST["nome"];
$email = "visualexpert@gmail.com";
$mensagem = $_POST["mensagem"];
$assunto = $_POST["assunto"];
$email_from = $_POST["email_from"];
//formato o campo da mensagem
$mensagem = wordwrap( $mensagem, 50, "
", 1);
//valido os emails
if (!ereg("^([0-9,a-z,A-Z]+)([.,_]([0-9,a-z,A-Z]+))*[@]([0-9,a-z,A-Z]+)([.,_,-]([0-9,a-z,A-Z]+))*[.]([0-9,a-z,A-Z]){2}([0-9,a-z,A-Z])?$", $email)){
echo"<center>Digite um email valido</center>";
echo "<center><a href=\"java script:history.go(-1)\">Voltar</center></a>";
exit;
}
if (!ereg("^([0-9,a-z,A-Z]+)([.,_]([0-9,a-z,A-Z]+))*[@]([0-9,a-z,A-Z]+)([.,_,-]([0-9,a-z,A-Z]+))*[.]([0-9,a-z,A-Z]){2}([0-9,a-z,A-Z])?$", $email_from)){
echo "<center>Digite um email valido</center>";
echo "<center><a href=\"java script:history.go(-1)\"><center>Voltar</center></a>";
exit;
}
$arquivo = isset($_FILES["arquivo"]) ? $_FILES["arquivo"] : FALSE;
if(file_exists($arquivo["tmp_name"]) and !empty($arquivo)){
$fp = fopen($_FILES["arquivo"]["tmp_name"],"rb");
$anexo = fread($fp,filesize($_FILES["arquivo"]["tmp_name"]));
$anexo = base64_encode($anexo);
fclose($fp);
$anexo = chunk_split($anexo);
$boundary = "XYZ-" . date("dmYis") . "-ZYX";
$mens = "--$boundary\n";
$mens .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bits\n";
$mens .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"ISO-8859-1\"\n\n"; //plain
$mens .= "$mensagem\n";
$mens .= "--$boundary\n";
$mens .= "Content-Type: ".$arquivo["type"]."\n";
$mens .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$arquivo["name"]."\"\n";
$mens .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n";
$mens .= "$anexo\n";
$mens .= "--$boundary--\r\n";
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers .= "From: \"$nome\" <$email_from>\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$boundary\"\r\n";
$headers .= "$boundary\n";
//envio o email com o anexo
mail($email,$assunto,$mens,$headers);
echo"Email enviado com Sucesso!";
}
//se não tiver anexo
else{
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "From: \"$nome\" <$email_from>\r\n";
//envia o email sem anexo
mail($email,$assunto,$mensagem, $headers);
echo"Email enviado com Sucesso!";
}
?>
```

Comment: Já funcionou alguma vez? qual a versão do php? se possível é melhor usa o phpMailer ou swiftMailer para enviar emails com anexo.

Comment: Verificou a caixa de Spam?

Comment: Pode ser o gmail que bloqueou o marcou o dominio `hospedagemdesites.ws` como spammer. Provavelmente só entrando em contato com eles (é apenas um teoria)

Comment: Vamos lá @rray não funcionou nenhuma vez, nem com este nem com outro script mas ambos utilizam a mesma função mail()

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento sim, não está lá :(

Este servidor que estou utilizando para testes tem o DNS www apontado para outro lugar, mas o e-mail continua sendo local nele (é hospedagem locaweb)

Comment: e a versão do php?

Comment: É possível utilizar as versões 5.6, 5.5, 5.4, 5.3 e 5.2, sendo a versão 5.2 configurada como padrão. Uso a Locaweb @rray.